# Low Vgs MOSFET as switch

Tags: mosfet

I'm trying to figure out how I can switch this device on. I tried p-mosfet but it has too high Vgs and the difference between gate and source is really low. Is there any other way?[image]

Comment: Well, thats the question. How I can make it turn on via mosfet?

Comment: with that low gate-source voltage

Comment: I aware that the circuit is wrong, man. P-mos can be whatever you want eg. IRLML2244. How i can replace this circuit to work properly? DEVICE VDD is just a VDD pin of 74LS125

Comment: I want to switch on/off 74LS125 power but the Vgs is too low to use any mosfet? Is there any trick?

Comment: Try to define clearly  what you are level shifting or expecting with Out to IN . Some devices are tolerance of Vout=5V on V+=3.3  So define the devices on each side and supply or the worst case levels for power.   you show 3.7-4.2 Vcc yet LS125 operates from 4.5 to 5.5

Comment: I just want to siwtch on/off VDD of 74LS125. This ilustration was just a not working example. I aware of it. I just want to switch it on/off. How I can do that. On the gate we have STM32 (3.3V device). Actually I made a mistake, there is a 3.3V regulator on the drain side. this power needs to be delivered to 3.3V device which is 74LS125

Comment: "I just want to siwtch on/off VDD of 74LS125" - why?

Comment: I want to save power

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see the problem with your connection ? Here:

[image]

So with this configuration, unfortunately, you can't turn that mostfet on or off. It will always conduct! When you place a mostfet, make sure you look at that diode and where it is pointing!

Try something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5tz4g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Make sure to always limit your GPIO with series resistors as shown. (Or you'll blow up that pin)

Use an npn-bjt as shown to drive a mosfet. You'll get better current capacity. Also, that schematic is just an example. Please pick the best values using the components' datasheets.

Comment: Can I change Q1 to mosfet also?

Comment: Yes you can use an N-Mosfet there.

Comment: Is there any way to reduce power? I need this swicth to a low power device. I also replaced Rlimit with 10k, R1 and R3 with 470k, Q1 to MOSFET i get quite a lot of current wasted

Comment: If you used N-mosfet as Q1, then you don't need to use 10K resistor on Rlimit because N-mos will not draw current from gate when it is on. And by using big Rlimit, you are causing the Nmos to turn on late, which will increase switching losses. Use 220Ohm there instead. The same thing goes for R1. Higher R1, higher switching losses. R3 can be high, that's okay. If switching losses are not your concern, and you are worried of Q1 wasted current, then you should use higher R1. But M1 will turn on very slow. If you need better results, buy a p-mos driver.

Answer (score 0):

Vgs has nothing to do with the problem. Drain and source are reversed and the body diode is conducting. This is what you need to do.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFrQlK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The IRLML2244 is fine for switching a 3.3V rail. Just pull the gate to ground to turn it on, set the pin to an input to turn it off. If the micro's input leakage is too high, play with the R1 value, or add another transistor NPN BJT or N channel FET in place of the GPIO pin.